# Bracha on thunder and lightning - how often?

Tags: halacha, blessing, weather, natural-phenomenon

If you are in a rainstorm with thunder and lightning - you make the Brachos for them. What happens if the storm ends and then a few hours later (same day) it is raining again. Do you make another Bracha or is it only said once a day?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As long as it looks overcast, it's once per day.

If it totally completely absolutely clears up bright and shiny, then later thunderstorms, you'd make a new bracha.

SO:

Once per day,

OR

Once per cloudy episode

Whichever is more.

(See Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 227:2 and Mishna Berura sk 8)

Comment: Beat me again (11 seconds!)

Comment: Just to clarify most poskim hold that 'day' in this context starts at Olot HaShachar and not Tzeit HaKochavim.

Comment: I think that if you follow the same storm - E.g. the storm moves from west to east. You were in the storm, it left your area, then you drive eastward and you're in the same storm - you do not need to make the bracha, again. I think I asked this question on this site, and I'll try to find it.

Comment: Found it! http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61057/5275. The answer, there, seems similar to this answer, but, I don't think it answers that question.

Answer (score 8):

If by "ends", you mean the sky cleared, then yes you make another one. However, just stopping and starting doesn't count.

On an aside, if it's the next day you make a Bracha even if the sky didn't clear.

Comment: pity that there is no an option to accept two answers :)

Comment: +1. This answer is correct as far as I know also. But a source would be nice.

Comment: @msh210 Simplest source: look in Artscroll Siddur