# Should you make one or two of each set of brachot during a hurricane and how often?

Tags: blessing

See [this M.Y. question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9639/5275) regarding the brachot to say on witnessing a hurricane.

Excerpt:

> Upon seeing/feeling uncommonly strong winds (a hurricane would
>   qualify), on feeling an earthquake, lightning, or thunder, the
>   Shulchan Aruch says to say Oseh Ma'aseh vereshit, and "if you want"
>   Shekocho u'gvurato malei olam. (OC 227) The nosei kelim there say that
>   the custom is to say Oseh Ma'aseh vereshit on lightning, and Shekocho
>   u'gvurato malei olam on thunder

So, the same *bracha* or possibly both brachot that are said for the hurricane winds are also said for lightning and thunder. A hurricane includes winds and frequently lightning and thunder. If one has said the barchot on the wind, does this exempt saying the brachot when seeing the lightning and hearing the thunder?

How often should one say these brachot? Every hurricane has an eye, which is an area of clear skies (usually) and calm winds in the center of the storm. [This M.Y. answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3534/5275) says that if the sky clears, and then clouds return, one should make a new bracha.

However, [this M.Y. answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/61126/5275) *proposes* that it may not apply if it's the same storm. The answer is vague, b/c O.C. only says "if the sky clears." If the eye passes over your area, should you make a new set of brachot when the thunder & lightning and wind return? Is it considered a "new" storm, in terms of halacha?

Comment: "If one has said the barchot on the wind, does this exempt saying the brachot when seeing the lightning and hearing the thunder?" Wouldn't that logic imply that saying a blessing on lightning exempts the thunder??

Comment: "Every hurricane has an eye" Most places don't go through the eye though. It's pretty small compared to the whole storm (only about 30 miles in diameter, maybe 15 minutes).

Comment: Double AA is correct, but to clarify, when the eye passes over, it is a short respite from the storm and then it resumes with full force.  To one experiencing the storm, it is clearly the SAME storm.  Keep in mind, the storm will be going on for many hours and the time the eye passes will be relatively short.  Here in Houston, waiting on tropical storm Cindy, we will get heavy thunderstorms and heavy wind starting this evening and going thr0ugh Thursday.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3533/bracha-on-thunder-and-lightning-how-often